# React-Native: Is there anyway to track whether user has read the whole content available on the current page?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have this usecase where I want to track how much of available content user has read. In the application, there is one scrollView inside which multiple subsections are present which are also scrollable. How can I track the percentage of total content the user has read overall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this component to get the percentage of the scroll

```
import React from 'react';
import {ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const scrollPercentage = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
  return ((layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y)/contentSize.height) * 100;
};

function PercentageScrollView({onReadPercentageChanged, children}) {

  return <ScrollView
    onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
      onReadPercentageChanged(scrollPercentage(nativeEvent));
    }}
    scrollEventThrottle={400}
  >
    {children}
  </ScrollView>
}

export default PercentageScrollView;
```

Use in your component like this :

```
<PercentageScrollView onReadPercentageChanged={(readPercentage)=>{
  setPercentage(readPercentage);
}}>
  <View>
    ...
  </View>
</PercentageScrollView>
```

Comment: I want to rephrase the question, I want to track continuously how much of the total content the user has read. So, basically at first the content read is 0% and as the user keeps on scrolling it increases accordingly.

Comment: Was that what you were looking for ?

Comment: The basic solution seems to work, if there is any other issue, I will comment the query.